# How to get only active Language values from KnowlegeArticleVersion object?

Tags: apex, knowledge

Here is my code from Anonymous Console:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = KnowledgeArticleVersion.Language.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : picklistValues) {
       System.debug('Language '+picklistEntry.getLabel()+ ' is Active'+ 
                     picklistEntry.isActive());
}
```

[image: Here is Debug Log of this code]

[image: Here is a Knowledge Article Settings. You can see that German and Italian were marked as Inactive, but in debug log they are still active]

You can see that German and Italian were marked as Inactive, but in debug log they are still active. How can I get only Active Language from KnowledgeArticleVersion object?

Comment: picklistEntry.isActive() is used to find if the value must be displayed on the UI, not to check the actual status. You must try some other approach.